# React Native: How to get data from JSON with different keys and display it?

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I'm new to react-native and JavaScript. I have JSON that looks like this:

```
{"AB1281":{"id":"AB1281","score":90,"status":"SUCCESS"},
"CA9412":{"id":"CA9412","score":40,"status":"FAILED"},
"GG1921":{"id":"GG1921","score":80,"status":"SUCCESS"}}
```

Suppose I get this JSON from this code:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource: responseJson,
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    });
  };
```

As you can see, all keys are varied and different ("AB1281", "CA9412", "GG1921"). how can I parse this data and render it in listview?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use FlatList you must have an array.
Here you have an object with three properties.
Or you can use ScrollView to loop through your object properties:

```
<ScrollView>
  {Object.keys(dataSource).map((key, index) => (
    <Text>{data[key].id}</Text>
  ))}
</ScrollView>
```

As react native doc says if your list is going to be long it's better to use FlatList.
see [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/using-a-listview).

Comment: or maybe convert the object to array and use flatlist.